# JQuery UI & ASP .NET : Slow performance on lists with images

Tags: asp.net, jquery-ui

We use JQuery UI to display image buttons (asp:Linkbutton, asp:HyperLink, ..) in our lists and we notice very slow performance when the page loads.

The page seems loaded except the images. At this point - under chrome - the loading circle is still spinning and that's where the user has to wait 10 seconds! for the images to load  :

[image]

After 10 secs the images are finally displayed :

[image]

It's seems to be related to the jquery-ui image (ui-icons_ffffff_256x240.png) :

[image: network_chrome]

The jquery-ui and the css are referenced in the head section of the Master page:

```
<link type="text/css" href="/Ressources/css/jquery-ui-1.8.7.mf.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/jquery-1.5.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.13.custom.min.js"></script>
```

This is how the image is set:

in ASPX:

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="lkBtnEditFDM" runat="server" Text="Modif" CssClass="editFButton" OnClick="lkBtnAddFDM_Click" ></asp:LinkButton>
```

in JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
..
  $(".editFButton").button({
    text: false,
    icons: {
      primary: 'ui-icon-pencil'
    }
  });
});
```

Do you have any idea as to why this huge lag happens? thanks!

Comment: how is the jquery-ui css file referenced?

Comment: Move your jQuery and CSS file to the saperate file...

Comment: Can you give us the live url to check it out ?

Comment: @Aristos : Unfortunately no, it is an internal web site

Comment: Can you also post the code where you hook up the image buttons in the lists?

Comment: It could be because the page is not finished "loading" and when the JavaScript hook-up it set the images.

Move the "script" tags outside of the head (end of body) and also do a $(document).ready( ..... console.log("loaded") ...) 

It might gives you some info about when the css is really set with the jQuery buttons.

Comment: @AndyRefuerzo I provided you more code

Comment: I provided you some more code

Comment: It is possible that your list is long or huge that's why the hooking up of the jquery button inside `$(document).ready(function () {` is not firing immediately. In the 3rd image you posted, check if there is anything loading/pending when you reach the `about:blank` part (during the 10sec lag). If there are any, then that is blocking the loading of the button icons.